# How can I show that this has a reflexive closure?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assume R is a relation on A.

Show that R ∪ ΔA is the reflexive closure of R.

What I thought is, that if R is an union with ΔA, it must mean that all a in A are (a,a).
But I don't know if this is good argument.

Comment: What is $\Delta A$?  Is it $\{(a,b)\in A\times A \mid a=b\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reflexive closure of $R$ is the *smallest* reflexive relation that contains $R$.  So your argument needs three parts:

1. $R\cup\Delta A$ contains $R$
2. $R\cup\Delta A$ is reflexive
3. If $S$ is a proper subset of $R\cup\Delta A$, then it fails (1) or (2).

Point 1 is trivial (it follows from basic properties of set union).  But you need to establish 2 and 3.

Item 3 states that $R\cup\Delta A$ is the *smallest* relation that satisfies (1) and (2), because it says that if $S$ is smaller than $R\cup\Delta A$, then it does *not* satisfy (1) and (2).  This is a crucial point.

The argument you stated in your post (“all $a$ in $A$ are $(a,a)$”) does not make sense to me.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Very helpful. My argument did not make any sense indeed (Hayden's comment is actually the appropriate one). However, I don't really understand point 3. But I will look into it! Thanks again.

Comment: I have elaborated on what item 3 is about.

Comment: Very nice of you! It is clear now! Thank you very much, I appreciate it!